# Replacement for searchForStream method in ElasticSearch java api client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am migrating a java application from elastic search high level client to java api client, as required for Spring Boot 3, as it no longer supports 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.ElasticsearchRestTemplate'...

I'm unable to find a new way to search with a stream!
Here is an old code snippet...

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder builder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder() //
    .withQuery(q) //
    .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 1000)); //

NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = builder.build();

Stream<X> list = elasticsearchTemplate.searchForStream(searchQuery, X.class).stream();
```

I'm using Spring Boot 3, Elastic Search 8.5.3 and the Java Api 8.5.3...

Here is the gradle dependency...

```
implementation group: 'co.elastic.clients', name: 'elasticsearch-java', version: "8.5.3"
```

Comment: are you using Spring data Elasticsearch ? Can you please provide maven dependancy ?

Comment: Hi Sagar, I'm not using it because it was deprecated and a lot of classes were removed, including "elasticsearchTemplate", and that is the reason why i'm asking....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ElasticsearchOperations.searchForStream(Query query, Class<T> clazz)` is available in Spring Data Elasticsearch 5.0 as it was in 4.4. This did not change at all. What has changed is that Spring Data Elasticsearch now uses the new client from Elasticsearch.

What has changed is that you cannot use the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` as this was creating native queries for the old client. You will now need to use the `NativeQueryBuilder`.

As for the solution you suggest in your answer: You cannot just use a reactive implementation as a replacement for the existing imperative one.

And the easiest solution would be to not have a `ElasticsearchTemplate` injected, but use the interface `ElasticsearchOperations` instead.

Comment: @PJ Thanks! I had a bunch of technical issues and I wasnt able to find the new class and the method... With your help, I could...

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to find, as I could not find it in the official documentation, but
the replacement for deprecated

**'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.ElasticsearchRestTemplate'**

is

**'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate'**

Regarding the "searchForStream", now the searches can be converted into streams...

Also you need to include into gradle/maven the updated dependency...

```
api group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: "5.0.0"
```